# PHP display server IP Address

Tags: php, ip-address, ip

I'm working on a website, and one of the things I would like to do is display MY IP address to users.  The website is made with CodeIgniter, so I was looking to find my server IP with PHP.  The IP address may change (it's a roamer), so I'd like to find it dynamically, not just hard code it.  I tried this:

```
$data['hostname'] = NULL;
$data['ip'] = NULL;
$var = gethostname();
if ($var === FALSE) {
  $var = NULL;
} else {
  $data['hostname'] = $var;
  $data['ip']   = gethostbyname($var);
}
```

However, instead of giving me the Hostname and the IP, I got: "Moria" and "127.0.1.1".  Not quite what I am looking for. Rather, it should say "Moria.student.rit.edu" for the Hostname, and the IP address.  Any help?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']`. It will be the IP address that the server is listening on. You can use DNS functions (e.g., `gethostbyaddr()`) to get the host name.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php.

Answer (score 1):

for server ip address
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];

and for server port
$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];

Answer (score -9):

If your laravel application is running on an internal server, you can use the following to get the external address of the server:

```
 $external_ip = exec('curl http://ipecho.net/plain; echo');
```

Comment: Evil, bad and wrong. This code is very poor and should never be used in production. You should use the intrinsic PHP Curl library. This avoids forking the http process to spawn a shell. Who knows whether `curl` is in the path? What's the `echo` for? In any event, a web server should never be allowed outside your organization's perimeter. If it has to, it should pass via an internal proxy.

Comment: Not a single mention of laravel exists on this entire page accept yours. -1