# show server IP on application while you are using a domain and a load balancer to control traffic on 6 server

Tags: javascript, java, php, drupal, server

I have 06 server and a same application on them,I have a domain to access all of them ans a load balancer that's located by a domain..to control the traffic on application. I want to show server ip on the application to rectify some issue on support level. How? I'm using php with drupal

Comment: It is not any different than if you were running one server. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4420474/1508101).

Comment: And why the tags for java and javascript?

Comment: Best way I would see is to store clients IP addresses on each server and if the client calls in for support, then you can search on these logs to find out  the appropriate one.